# How to remove certain sets of punctuation bet retain others in a string?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating a URL from various parts in order to make a phone call using

```
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kCallURLBase stringByAppendingString:numberStr]];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
// kCallURLBase is "tel:"
```

If numberStr contains '(' or ')' then url is null, and from reading other postings on here people have been having difficulty if the number contains spaces or '-' etc. So I added the following:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
[charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
[charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
[charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
NSArray *arrayWithNumbers = [self.number componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
NSString *numberStr = [arrayWithNumbers componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

However some numbers might be of the form *56 as they are being made from a handset in which case the * character needs to be retained. How can I remove all the other unnecessary characters but retain the *?

Alternatively, is there a better solution then this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a character set using the characters you do want (digits, #, and *), then split your input string on any characters that are not in that set, and join the results back together.  That will leave you with only valid characters in your string.

```
NSString *numberStr = @"(212) 555-1212 *99";

NSCharacterSet *illegalCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890*#"] invertedSet];
NSString *convertedStr = [[numberStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:illegalCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

// convertedStr => 2125551212*99
```

Comment: Very elegant! We might also want add the + for globally unique phone numbers. There is actually an RFC for tel URIs: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt  It appears that most phone number punctuation is allowed; spaces seem to be the main no-no.

Comment: On closer inspection of the RFC, I see that - . ( and ) are the allowed characters in tel URIs. So the complete allowed character set would be `@"+0123456789*#-.()"`. (Though if you wanted to be really precise, + should only appear at the beginning of a number and never with * or #.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that instead of filtering out disallowed characters, it'd be better to just take the good ones. Those would basically be: digits, *, #. So you could just iterate through the string, and collect characters representing digits, *, # in an array, and then join components of this array.

Probably the easy way to iterate over the string is to use something like:

```
const char *the_string = [numberString UTF8String];
```

Then just iterate from `the_string[0]` to `the_string[ strlen(the_string) - 1 ]`.

And you could fairly easy test for digits either using `isdigit(the_string[i])` from `ctype.h`, or doing `if (the_string[i] >= '0' && the_string[i] <= '9')`.